# How to reach /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps on remote host from Jenkins via scp plug-in

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the *scp* plug-in on Jenkins to convey my project's WAR it has freshly built to a remote host.

By hand, I would copy that WAR to my user on that host, then go there myself, get root (sudo) and copy the WAR up to */var/lib/tomcat6/webapps* where Tomcat would instantly deploy it.

However, as I can't find a way to use *tomcat6* as the user of *scp* since user *tomcat6* has no discoverable password, I'm at a loss to tell Jenkins how to do this without my keyboard interaction--rendering using Jenkins for continuous deployment useless.

I'm running Jenkins on Precise server and the remote server where the WAR is to be deployed is also running Precise.

Thanks to anyone reading this question and profuse thanks to anyone who can set me straight as to the smart way to accomplish this.

Here's the relevant output (failure) from Jenkins:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 29 seconds
[SCP] Connecting to app-1.site
[SCP] uploading file: '/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/myapp.war'
ERROR: Failed to upload files
3: Permission denied
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:485)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:439)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:406)
    at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPSite.upload(SCPSite.java:239)
    at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPRepositoryPublisher.perform(SCPRepositoryPublisher.java:211)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:776)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:726)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1600)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:241)
Build step 'Publish artifacts to SCP Repository' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

There are two solutions to try, but I don't see either as good. The real way, in my opinion, would be to be able to use *tomcat6* as a bonafide user to begin with. For that, it would have to have a controllable password.

**Solutions to try**

1) Endow *tomcat6* with a password. Don't know if a) this can be done, b) it will work even if we try or c) whether this will simply break the Tomcat installation which I don't feel like doing now. Needs research.

2) Jack the privileges on */var/lib/tomcat6/webapps* such that my user or another I create specially for the job can copy to that path AND Tomcat be willing to deploy whatever gets copied there. May need to modify permissions on the WAR file from ant during build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply make subdirectory */var/lib/tomcat6/webapps* writable

```
/var/lib/tomcat6 $ chmod a+w webapps
```

This works with a minimum of effort and I think anyone observing the permissions on this subdirectory will not be too surprised.

Comment: This was my solution too, but it still didn't work for me. I later noticed that the jar file I was trying to copy was already in the directory and I did not have write permissions on jar file. So I had to do the same for the file as well.